# Is there a way to change the artifact nuget authors name from (default?) VssAdministrator to my preferred authors name?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-devops, nuget

Question is in the title.
Here some images to better understand what i mean.

> [image]

but i dont understand why it does not take the authors names from the package settings in vs.

> [image]

therefore i would like to ask if i need to change something or if i do something wrong while working with azure devops and vs c# projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be safe that `MyName` will be used as author you can define your own `.nuspec`-file and then set your name. (Then `nuget` completely ignores the settings in the `.csproj`-file when building your `.nupkg`-file.) Then you can define a buildstep (or use an addon) which executes something like `nuget pack mypackage.nuspec`. This ensures that azure devops does not insert any custom properties.

Comment: thanks worked. btw i am new and didnt know that it does not work this way i did